# How to add leading zeros into existing Column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one column (**zip varchar(10)**) in MySQL.
I am giving some value examples of this columns.

**1.** 576
**2.** 5768
**3.** 57689

I want to replace all three digits with adding **00** as prefix, all four digits with adding **0** prefix. 
So after doing this operation my values should be,

**1.** 00576
**2.** 05768
**3.** 57689

Is it possible with any MySQL query? Any ideas?

Comment: try [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query uses the LPAD function suggested by georstef.

```
UPDATE <tablename>
SET zip = LPAD(zip,5,'0');
```

Comment: This will also shorten values of `zip` that are over five characters in length; if that's not the desired behavior, then do a conditional test of the length of zip first, e.g. `IF(CHAR_LENGTH(zip)<5,LPAD(zip,5,'0'),zip)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stored procedure for this, inside your procedure check if `CHAR_LENGTH()` == 3 (you could use a variable instead of hardwiring 3 here)than 
use an if statement to set number of leading zeros to a variable. Than you could update the column with a concat function with the variable that has the leading zeros.

Comment: It is possible without procedure. see given answer.